# Mint.com's awesome categorization widget

Tags: javascript, web-applications, jquery-plugins

Mint.com has possibly the best category/subcategory control I've seen.  It is a combination of autocomplete and a two-level menu - complete with keyboard support.

Does something like this exist as a jQuery plugin or stand-alone javascript control?  If not, what approach would you use to make one.  It looks like they are using [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/).

Here is a [screencast for demonstration](http://www.screencast.com/users/lancefisher/folders/Jing/media/a92e0888-0298-4260-ba05-28cefb49db5d).

Comment: I tagged this as subjective because your opening statement seems very 'strong' to say the least

Comment: It's not subjective. It is the best one - possibly.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories is close, just does not have the multi-level expanding results or letter highlighting.